# Read 1GB size excel with 1.5 Records per sheet to Dataset

Tags: excel, vsto, openxml, office-interop

I am trying to import large excel files to database using .NET application in which I will do some customized cleansing and processing of data. The excel file will have sheets with 255 columns and 150,000 rows. I tried different solutions such as *Microsoft.JET/ACE provider*, *OpenXML/OfficeOpenXML* and *LinqToExcel*. I get `OutofMemory` exceptions with both Microsoft adapter and openxml. Please let me know how to deal with it.

Comment: Please avoid [regional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Asian_numbering_system) numbering system.

Comment: Is the issue with the adapter or from reading all the data in at once? That is, if the data was used in a streaming fashion, does this problem exist?

Comment: @pst : I tried using streaming, then I got exception: "There is not enough space on the disk."

Comment: @JigarPandya: I am trying different solutions by googling. I cannot up/down vote. Its not available for my reputation level

Comment: @Kiran Clean up some disk space! That is not good and may also be reducing the amount of available swap (and thus might be leading to "Out of Memory" exceptions sooner than need be). In any case, that's a *different* issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Integration Services to import an Excel file into SQL Server 2005? You can use Integration Services (a wonderful tool) for extracting, transforming, and loading data. Common uses for Integration Services include: loading data into the database; changing data into to or out from your relational database structures.

You can call this services from you .net code again and again to perform the task in repetitive manor.  If not from .net code you can schedule it as well.

see this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205 sample application for the same.

If you dont want to use SSIS. You could use the following ready to use open tools for the same.

- http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14639/Fast-Excel-file-reader-with-basic-functionality
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16210/Excel-Reader

This should help you.

Comment: I cannot go with integration services, in fact the application has been developed to avoid integration services. I am trying different options.

Comment: Can you please provide some inputs what is the current status of the above problem, how you solved and etc.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The issue has not been fixed yet. As of now we have compromised with the requirements and kept a file size limit to 254mb to user.